# table x has no column named y

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have problem when i send data to database.

> Error:
>
> E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting linka=14 jedu=false cas=2018-05-03
>   17:33:05 id_veh=1234
>                     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table m_register has no column named linka (code 1): , while compiling:
>   INSERT INTO m_register(linka,jedu,cas,id_veh) VALUES (?,?,?,?)

This is my class where is addData called. Error was trigerred by addData method

```
      package com.example.pc.mhdapp;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    private static final String TAG = "DatabaseHelper";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "m_register";
    private static final String COL1 = "ID";
    private static final String COL2 = "id_veh";
    private static final String COL3 = "linka";
    private static final String COL4 = "jedu";
    private static final String COL5 = "cas";
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
    super(context, TABLE_NAME, null, 1);

}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "  (ID INTEGER(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
        COL2 + " VARCHAR(11)," +
        COL3 + " VARCHAR(50)," +
        COL4 + " VARCHAR(3)," +
        COL5 + " DATETIME)";
db.execSQL(createTable);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean addData(String id_vehl, String linkas, String jedus, String cass){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL2,  id_vehl);
    contentValues.put(COL3,  linkas);
    contentValues.put(COL4,  jedus);
    contentValues.put(COL5,  cass);

    Log.d(TAG, "addDATA: adding " +  id_vehl+ ", "+linkas+ ", "+jedus+ ", "+cass+ " to " + TABLE_NAME);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null, contentValues);
    if(result == -1){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Here `id_veh` and `jedu ` are type of integer and you are putting string.

Comment: I changed it and still same error

Comment: Okay. if you have changed DB schema or update table schema. TRy to uninstall app and reinstall it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you changed the Database schema by adding other columns, try to uninstall and re-install the app, it will work.
TIP: when you modify your database schema the next time, please upgrade the version in onUpgrade